# rails nomethoderror only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

I have a rails app with google calendar API integrated. App is deployed on heroku. The following code is working in localhost but I getting nomethoderror in production as shown below. Why is this happening?

errors for get_own_events:

```
Attempting refresh of access token & retry of request
2016-02-10T13:24:34.161850+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-02-10T13:24:34.161853+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
2016-02-10T13:24:34.161854+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/google_calendar_api.rb:91:in `get_own_events'
2016-02-10T13:24:34.161855+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:18:in `index'
```

errors for get busy events:

```
2016-02-10T13:24:00.716112+00:00 app[web.1]: Attempting refresh of access token & retry of request
2016-02-10T13:24:00.779120+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass):
2016-02-10T13:24:00.779121+00:00 app[web.1]:   lib/google_calendar_api.rb:38:in `get_busy_events'
2016-02-10T13:24:00.779121+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/events_controller.rb:20:in `index'
```

events_controller

```
  if params['start'] && params['end']
    @start_time = params['start'].to_datetime.rfc3339
    @end_time = params['end'].to_datetime.rfc3339
    @timezone = params['timezoneParam']
    if @user == @current_user
      @results = get_own_events(@google, @start_time, @end_time, @timezone)
    else
      @results = get_busy_events(@google, @start_time, @end_time, @timezone)
    end
  end
```

get_own_events method:

```
def get_own_events(social_object, start_time, end_time, timezone)
  client = init_google_api_calendar_client(social_object)
  old_token = client.authorization.access_token
  service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

  #API request/response
  result_raw = client.execute(
    :api_method => service.events.list,
    :parameters => { 'calendarId' => social_object.email,
                   'timeMin' => start_time,
                   'timeMax' => end_time,
                   'timeZone' => timezone },
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

  #token refresh if needed
  new_token = client.authorization.access_token
  if old_token != new_token
    social_object.update_attribute(:token, new_token)
    get_own_events(social_object, start_time, end_time, timezone)
  end

  #API response parsing
  result = JSON.parse(result_raw.body)['items']
  #result_timezone = JSON.parse(result_raw.body)['timeZone']

  #changing response to fullcalendar format
  formatted_event_array = []

  result.each do |event| #THIS IS LINE 91
    start_time = event['start']['dateTime'].to_datetime.rfc822
    end_time = event['end']['dateTime'].to_datetime.rfc822
    #timezone = result_timezone
    all_day = false
    title = event['summary']
    formatted_event = {}
    formatted_event['title'] = title
    formatted_event['start'] = start_time
    formatted_event['end'] = end_time
    formatted_event['allDay'] = all_day
    formatted_event_array << formatted_event
  end

  return formatted_event_array
end
```

get_busy_events method:

```
def get_busy_events(social_object, start_time, end_time, timezone)
  client = init_google_api_calendar_client(social_object)
  old_token = client.authorization.access_token
  service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

  #API request/response
  result_raw = client.execute(
    :api_method => service.freebusy.query,
    :body => JSON.dump({ 
            :timeMin => start_time,
            :timeMax => end_time,
            :timeZone => timezone,
            :items => [{ :id => social_object.email }]}),
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

  #token refresh if needed
  new_token = client.authorization.access_token
  if old_token != new_token
    social_object.update_attribute(:token, new_token)
    get_busy_events(social_object,start_time, end_time, timezone)
  end

  #API response parsing 
  result = JSON.parse(result_raw.body)['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy'] #THIS IS LINE 38

  #changing response to fullcalendar format
  formatted_event_array = []

  result.each do |event|
    start_time = event['start'].to_datetime.rfc822
    end_time = event['end'].to_datetime.rfc822
    formatted_event = {}
    formatted_event['title'] = 'busy'
    formatted_event['start'] = start_time
    formatted_event['end'] = end_time
    #no allDay in freebusy response, so time difference must be checked
    if event['start'].to_datetime + 1.day <= event['end'].to_datetime
      formatted_event['allDay'] = true
    else
      formatted_event['allDay'] = false
    end
    formatted_event_array << formatted_event 
  end

  return formatted_event_array
end
```

Comment: Which lines are 38 and 91 in `lib/google_calendar_api.rb`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively it's this

```
result = JSON.parse(result_raw.body)['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy']
```

If `JSON.parse(result_raw.body)['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy']` is nil then this

```
result.each do |event|
# code
end
```

Is attempting to iterate over nil.

You could fix that with a guard clause

```
return formatted_event_array if result.nil?
result.each do |event|
# code
end
```

But to me that's papering over the cracks somewhat.  The other error is because of that same line.

Assuming 
`parsed_body = JSON.parse(result_raw.body)`

By chaining the hash calls without checking it'll throw your error if
`parsed_body['calendars']` is nil or if
`parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email]` is nil

So effectively you want to check if those both exist, and that `parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy']` exists.  If they don't then presumably return the empty array

So

```
if parsed_body['calendars'] && parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email] && parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy']
```

Comment: j-dexx, with which method should I check if it exists?

Comment: You could use `.present?` but you should be able to use a standard if

Comment: j-dexx, could you update your answer? I ran into this one a few times already and I'd like to make sure from now I will use it properly every time. So if you could show me some sample code and list some situations where this approach should be used it would be super awesome.

Comment: Done, it's a simple if that you could probably refactor to improve

Comment: j-dexx can you put it into my sample code? My main question is that what I should return when it's nil.

Comment: I would assume an empty array as an array is whatever is calling your method is expecting.

Comment: j-dexx, sorry for being so slow, but I'm not good at ruby yet. Could you tell me what part I should put in the if statement. Let's say I will put in it the return formatted_event_array as well. In that case the result will be returned if the statement is not true,but then result doesn't even exist so I guess I will get another type of error. Could you put your answer in my code? Thanks for being so helpful!

Comment: `if` it exists process it, `else` return the empty `formatted_event_array`

Comment: j-dexx, one last question. Why is not enough to check only parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy'] rather than parsed_body['calendars'] && parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email] && parsed_body['calendars'][social_object.email]['busy'] ?

Comment: Because that will raise an error if any of the preceding method calls fail